# Haskell sequencelistIO [a -> IO a] -> a -> IO a

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I have the following problem:
I have a task to write a function taking a list of IO interactions and an initial value. The first action takes the initial value as an argument and the function shall pass its result (IO a) as an argument to the next interaction.

The latter expects data of type a, not IO a.
I don't get how to come over this obstacle.

Here is what I have:

```
seqList :: [a -> IO a] -> a -> IO a
seqList [] n = return n
seqList (inter:inters) n = do
        val <- inter n
        return $ seqList inters val
```

The problem is that val is of type (IO a) but the next IO expects a.
I tried something like

```
tmp <- unsafePerformIO val
```

after val <- ...

but that does not help and would be really bad style.
How can I solve this problem?

I want hints, no solutions,

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I edited it the following way:

```
seqList :: [a -> IO a] -> a -> IO a
seqList [] n = return n
seqList (inter:inters) n = do
            val <- inter n
            seqList inters val
```

as seqList inters val is already of the right type.

This should be ok or am I mistaken? It actually works for my examples.

I still am very new to this whole do-notation-monads-io-stuff as it seems.

Thank you very much for the hints.

Comment: You're pretty much there. Think about the type of `seqList inters val` (you don't always need `return :: a -> IO a` at the end of a do block).

Comment: `val` is not of type `IO a`: `inter n` is.

Comment: IOW you've misdiagnosed your problem. nothing wrong with your `val`, it is indeed of type `a`, as `n` is. re-read closely the error message that you get (and next time do please include it in full).

Comment: The edited version looks right.

Comment: Main thing about `do` blocks is, the type of the whole `do` expression is the same as each of its lines' type (either  by itself without the `<-`, or the expressions to the *right* of `<-`, excluding the `let` statements); so all  must be of the same type. 

It is `(Monad m) => m a` for some monad `m` and some type `a`. 

Let yourself be guided by the types.

Comment: The edited version is right, just commenting that you can change the type signature to `seqList :: Monad m => [a -> m a] -> a -> m a` and it will work the same way but also for other monads.

Comment: You could simplify this to `[a -> b] -> a -> [b]`, and then things might become clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The edited version is correct.

---

There's an interesting way of looking at this problem, though. One might analyze the type as follows

```
type Thing a = a -> IO a

seqList :: [Thing a] -> Thing a
```

In other words, `seqList` is a mechanism for combining `Thing`s. If we rewrite your working code a bit we can emphasize this.

```
seqList :: [Thing a] -> Thing a
seqList [] n = neutralThing n
seqList (thingHere : restOfThings) n = do
  let remainingThing = seqList restOfThings
  val <- thingHere
  remainingThing val

neutralThing :: Thing a
neutralThing a = return a
```

In particular, I've isolated three parts

- The neutral thing which is returned when the input list is empty
- The recursive bit which computes the "remaining thing" from the tail of the list
- The actual `do`-notation bit which "combines" things.

We can go even further

```
seqList :: [Thing a] -> Thing a
seqList [] = neutralThing
seqList (thingHere : restOfThings) = 
  combineThings thingHere (seqList restOfThings)

neutralThing :: Thing a
neutralThing a = return a

combineThings :: Thing a -> Thing a -> Thing a
combineThings thing1 thing2 n = do
  n'  <- thing1 n
  n'' <- thing2 n'
  return n''
```

Now we can recognize a general pattern: `seqList` is just a fold over the list.

```
seqList :: [Thing a] -> Thing a
seqList = foldr combineThings neutralThing
```

If we recognize that folds often expose [`Monoid`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) we can also detect how `Thing a` is a monoid for any choice of `a`

```
memptyThing :: Thing a
memptyThing = neutralThing

mappendThing :: Thing a -> Thing a -> Thing a
mappendThing = combineThings
```

Finally, if we're really clever, we can note that `Thing` inherits it monoidalness from the slightly more general construction of a [`Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html)—in particular, something called the [`Kleisli IO` category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli). If we were to use the `Kleisli` type itself there would be a lot of wrapping and unwrapping, but instead we can examine the types of `return` and `(>=>)` from `Control.Monad`.

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> (a -> m c)
```

With a little care we can see that these types are compatible with `memptyThing` and `mappendThing`. So, an ultimate solution to your problem is as follows

```
seqList :: [Thing a] -> Thing a
seqList = foldr (>=>) return
```

and we can finally note that this has a more general type if we like

```
seqList :: Monad m => [a -> m a] -> (a -> m a)
seqList = foldr (>=>) return
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of it is this: if you had two such actions, how would you chain them together?  [There's an operator in the `Control.Monad` library that does that](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).  It shouldn't be too hard to understand:

```
(>=>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (b -> m c) -> a -> m c
f >=> g = \a -> do
    b <- f a
    g b
```

And if you have that operator, then you can write `seqList` by taking the the list of actions and basically putting `>=>` between all of them.  [The standard `foldr` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldr), will do the trick; as the documentation says it does precisely that:

```
foldr f z [x1, x2, ..., xn] == x1 `f` (x2 `f` ... (xn `f` z)...)
```

So put those together, plus `return` for the empty list case, and you get:

```
import Control.Monad ((>=>))

seqList :: [a -> IO a] -> a -> IO a
seqList actions = foldr (>=>) return actions
```

Whose behavior can be described by these equations:

```
foldr (>=>) return [] == return
foldr (>=>) return [x1, ..., xn] == x1 >=> ... >=> xn >=> return
```

---

And let's work it out in more detail!  The definition of `foldr` is this:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr _ z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

So using that, we can rewrite my definition of `seqList` as such:

```
-- Use the definition of `foldr` to split this into two cases
seqList [] = return
seqList (action:actions) = action >=> foldr (>=>) return actions

-- Use the definition of `>=>` to spell out the second equation
seqList [] = return
seqList (action:actions) = \a -> do
    val <- action a
    foldr (>=>) return actions val

-- But by the definition of `seqList`, we can rewrite the last line
-- to this:
seqList [] = return
seqList (action:actions) = \a -> do
    val <- action a
    seqList actions val
```

And that's what you wrote on your second try!

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- Consider the case of having exactly 2 functions in your list and have a look at [`>=>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).
- Have a look at the [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) monoid, in particular at the signature of its [`mconcat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat). Try replacing `Endo a` with `a -> a` in the signature.
- How would the instance of the monadic generalization of `Endo`

  ```
  newtype EndoM m a = EndoM { appEndoM :: a -> m a }
  ```

  look like? What would be its `mempty` and `mappend`? What would be its `mconcat`?